# erase post excerpt limitation [×]

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development, themes, excerpt

i have a custom site  in homepage have problem of post excerpt  with max  35 word, now i want eliminate this limitation, after search in varius file the limitation and after individuate i have changed the (35) with big number, the post increase the number of caracter but on last have the dot (...) alternative of "readmore" now i want erase also this but not indivduate this,  how eliminate this limitation ???

this site use advanced custom field and Custom Post Type UI version: 0.8.3

the home have 2 file

1) home
2 home video

this is a file : http://textuploader.com/4u0l!

thanks

Comment: Please post your code directly in your question through an [edit]. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Slightly hard to follow you here, but from the file you posted there is a line:

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)."...";
```

Change it to:

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
```

Edit - Corrected line, should work now.

Comment: have comment and erase, but after this compare the text "array" instead of the text of the post

Comment: @themich I've updated the answer, make sure the line looks like that and it will work.

Comment: yes now not compare , but nothing the last 5-10 word not compare, why ? this also before your line code

Comment: sorry not 5-10 word but 5-10 characters

Comment: Use a higher number in the `the_excerpt();` call?

Comment: the_excerpt(); now not have value, what the_excerpt(); you refering ? thanks for answer